# this code in python about finding the longest sub-string , i need explaination

Tags: python, edx, longest-substring

i am trying to understand how this code works **behind the scene** , help appreciated

***explain this part please:***

```
MAX = ACCOUNT if len(ACCOUNT) > len(MAX) else MAX
ACCOUNT = ACCOUNT + c if c >= ACCOUNT[-1] else c
```

================================================

```
S = 'azcbobobegghaklbob'

ACCOUNT, MAX = S[0], ""

for c in S[1:] + " ":
    MAX = ACCOUNT if len(ACCOUNT) > len(MAX) else MAX
    ACCOUNT = ACCOUNT + c if c >= ACCOUNT[-1] else c

print('Longest substring in alphabetical order is:', MAX)
```

Comment: Do you have any *specific* question?

Comment: i don't understand this part 
    MAX = ACCOUNT if len(ACCOUNT) > len(MAX) else MAX
    ACCOUNT = ACCOUNT + c if c >= ACCOUNT[-1] else c

Comment: Then use a debugger or print out the variables to see what happens in every iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing out the code more clearly, it reads

```
s = 'azcbobobegghaklbob'
account = s[0]
maximum = ''
for c in s[1:] + ' ':
    if len(account) > len(maximum):
        maximum = account
    if c >= account[-1]:
        account += c
    else:
        account = c
print('Longest substring in alphabetical order is:', maximum)
```

`maximum` is the longest substring in alphabetical order so far. `account` is the current substring in alphabetical order that is being counted.

The for loop iterates over `'zcbobobegghaklbob '`. `account` starts out as the first character of the string. The first `if` block:

```
if len(account) > len(maximum):
    maximum = account
```

makes `maximum` equal to `account` if account has become larger than the previous maxumim.

`c` is the next character to be analyzed, right after the last character of `account`. The second `if` block:

```
if c >= account[-1]:
    account += c
```

Sees if `c` comes after the last character of `account`, alphabetically. If it does, it adds it to the end of `account`. The `>=` comparison on strings sorts them lexicographical for alphabetical characters of the same case.

The `else` cause:

```
else:
    account = c
```

clears the current substring and starts over if the next character is not in alphabetical order.

In the end, `maximum` will be what you want.

The extra `' '` is iterated over too so that the first if statement will be executed one more time before the loop finishes. In python, `' '` comes before all alphabetical characters, lexicographically.